# Activity не реагирует на сообщения из сервиса

Tags: android

Пытаюсь передать из сервиса сообщение в Activity

В активити Player написал следующее

```
public final static String SERVICE_PARAM_STATUS = "status";
public final static int SERVICE_STATUS = 0;
public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "ru.site.radios";

BroadcastReceiver br2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ***

    br2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int status = intent.getIntExtra(SERVICE_PARAM_STATUS, 0);

            if (status == SERVICE_STATUS) {
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(br2, filter);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterReceiver(br2);
}
```

В сервисе в методе onStartCommand написал следующее

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    context = this;
    this.stream = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_STREAM);
    this.radio = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_RADIO);

    if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        ***

    } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        intent.putExtra(Player.SERVICE_PARAM_STATUS, 0);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        ***
    }

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

По идее теперь, если из уведомления нажать Стоп, то должно быть передано значение 0, а в активити это значение будет проверено и иконка должна поменяться, но этого не происходит. Где ошибку допустил?

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver` ждёт Action == "ru.site.radios", заданный в `IntentFilter`

Comment: простите, не понял ваш ответ

Comment: Написан полный бред (извиняюсь, за резкость):
1) Отправляется не тот бродкаст
2) Отправляется вообще при старте сервиса, а не из уведомления.

Comment: Почему бред? Да, я не указал Intent brIntent = new Intent(Player.BROADCAST_ACTION);  , но мне уже ответили. А где еще ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Intent`, передаваемый в `sendBroadcast(intent);` должен удовлетворять требованиям фильтра, с которым ресивер зарегистрирован. В Вашем случае должны совпадать action:

```
     } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        Intent brIntent = new Intent(Player.BROADCAST_ACTION);
        brIntent.putExtra(Player.SERVICE_PARAM_STATUS, 0);
        sendBroadcast(brIntent);
        ***
     }
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Благодарности здесь принято выражать с помощью кнопочек слева от ответа.

Comment: а я уже выразил